# SQL - Calculations between fields that require conditional on selecting field for calculation

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with SQLite. I have a table T with two fields D1 and D2 that are both dates stored as text fields. I need to compute the number of days between a given date (let's call it DF) and D1 but when D2 is not NULL to use that instead.

So, let's say we were just computing the number of days between DF and D1 we would use:

```
SELECT CAST((julianday(DF) - julianday(D1)) AS INTEGER)
FROM T
```

Here though I need to implement the following pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT CAST((julianday(DF) - julianday(IF D2 IS NOT NULL USE D2 ELSE USE D1)) AS INTEGER)
FROM T
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT CAST((julianday(DF) - julianday(coalesce(D2, D1))) AS INTEGER)
FROM T
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I will select it as the answer shortly (have to wait another 5 mins to do so).